# How to enumerate theorems using letters with amsthm without losing the section numbering?

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm

It seems `\renewcommand{\theexample}{\Alph{example}}` makes the section numbering disappear. Is there a way to avoid this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\renewcommand*{\theexample}{\Alph{example}}

\begin{document}
\section{Intro}
\begin{example}[special curve]
Let something be something.
\end{example}
\section{Outro}
\begin{example}[special manifold]
Let something be something.
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do

```
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
```

then `\theexample` is defined by

```
\newcommand{\theexample}{\thesection.\arabic{example}}
```

and the `example` counter is reset any time `section` is stepped.

So you want to redefine `\theexample` by

```
\renewcommand*{\theexample}{\thesection.\Alph{example}}
```

Comment: FWIW, this also saved me for the LIPIcs 2016 style, where theorem numbering seems broken for theorems defined in the appendix. Just do a `\renewcommand*\thetheorem{\thesection.\arabic{theorem}}` in the appendix and it's fine again.